# Calculate matrix determinants with cublas device API

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, cublas

I am trying to evaluate a scalar function f(x), where x is a k-dimensional vector (i.e. f:R^k->R). During the evaluation, I have to perform many matrix operations: inversion, multiplication and finding matrix determinants and traces for matrices of moderate sizes (most of them are less than 30x30). Now I want to evaluate the function at many different xs at the same time by using different threads on the GPU. That is why I need the device api.

I have written the following codes to test calculating matrix determinants by the cublas device API, cublasSgetrfBatched, where I first find the LU decomposition of the matrix and calculate the product of all the diagonal elements in the U matrix. I have done this on both the GPU thread and CPU using the result returned by cublas. But the result from the GPU does not make any sense while the result on the CPU is correct. I have used cuda-memcheck, but found no errors. Could someone help shed some light on this issue? Many thanks.

```
    cat test2.cu

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>


__host__ __device__ unsigned int IDX(unsigned int i,unsigned  int j,unsigned int ld){return j*ld+i;}

#define PERR(call) \
  if (call) {\
   fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d Error [%s] on "#call"\n", __FILE__, __LINE__,\
      cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));\
   exit(1);\
  }
#define ERRCHECK \
  if (cudaPeekAtLastError()) { \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d Error [%s]\n", __FILE__, __LINE__,\
       cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));\
    exit(1);\
  }

__device__ float
det_kernel(float *a_copy,unsigned int *n,cublasHandle_t *hdl){
  int *info = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));info[0]=0;
  int batch=1;int *p = (int *)malloc(*n*sizeof(int));  
  float **a = (float **)malloc(sizeof(float *));
  *a = a_copy;  
  cublasStatus_t status=cublasSgetrfBatched(*hdl, *n, a, *n, p, info, batch);  
  unsigned int i1;
  float res=1;
  for(i1=0;i1<(*n);++i1)res*=a_copy[IDX(i1,i1,*n)];
  return res;
}

__global__ void runtest(float *a_i,unsigned int n){
  cublasHandle_t hdl;cublasCreate_v2(&hdl);
  printf("det on GPU:%f\n",det_kernel(a_i,&n,&hdl));  
  cublasDestroy_v2(hdl);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  float a[] = {
    1,   2,   3,
    0,   4,   5,
    1,   0,   0};
  cudaSetDevice(1);//GTX780Ti on my machine,0 for GTX1080
  unsigned int n=3,nn=n*n;
  printf("a is \n");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){    
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) printf("%f, ",a[IDX(i,j,n)]);    
    printf("\n");}
  float *a_d;
  PERR(cudaMalloc((void **)&a_d, nn*sizeof(float)));
  PERR(cudaMemcpy(a_d, a, nn*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
  runtest<<<1, 1>>>(a_d,n);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  ERRCHECK;

  PERR(cudaMemcpy(a, a_d, nn*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
  float res=1;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)res*=a[IDX(i,i,n)];
  printf("det on CPU:%f\n",res);
}

  nvcc -arch=sm_35 -rdc=true -o test test2.cu -lcublas_device -lcudadevrt
./test
a is 
1.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 
2.000000, 4.000000, 0.000000, 
3.000000, 5.000000, 0.000000, 
det on GPU:0.000000
det on CPU:-2.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

cublas device calls are *asynchronous*.

That means that they return control to the calling thread before the cublas call is finished.

If you want the calling thread to be able to process the results directly (as you are doing here to compute `res`), you must force a synchronization to wait for the results, before beginning computation.

You don't see this in the host side computation, because there is implicit synchronization of any device activity (including cublas device dynamic parallelism), before the parent kernel terminates.

So if you add add a synchronization after the device cublas call, like this:

```
cublasStatus_t status=cublasSgetrfBatched(*hdl, *n, a, *n, p, info, batch); 
cudaDeviceSynchronize(); // add this line
```

I think you'll see a match between the device computation and the host computation, as you expect.

Comment: Many thanks, Robert. Your suggestion works and can produce the expected results. I have another device routine which first uses cublasSgetrfBatched to get the LU decomposition and then cublasSgetriBatched to get the inverse from the LU output. Between them, do I need to use cudaDeviceSynchronize()? For small matrix (3 by 3), the results seem identical.

Comment: Another question is related to free the memory created by malloc in the device routine. If I use free() to deallocate the memory, cuda-memcheck will produce errors when the code is compiled with -lcublas_device(fine without it). Do you happen to have any ideas to get around this? Any consequences if I do not free the memory? Thx a lot.

Comment: Regarding the first question, cuda [stream semantics](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#streams) apply to device-side operations as well.  Device-side launches that don't specify a stream should launch into the default stream (per thread!), which means a device cublas operation A followed by a device cublas operation B issued by the same thread into the same stream should serialize.  B should not begin until A has finished.  Regarding the second question, I would need to know exactly where you are doing the `free()` operation.

Comment: In the codes of the original post,  I created *p inside the det_kernel with malloc. If I place free(p) at the end of the routine, cuda-memcheck will produce errors, though the program can still be run.

Comment: If that is the only change to the code of the original post, then that is a problem.  You need to add the synchronization I already mentioned in my answer.  If you don't, then you will free p while the asynchronous cublas routine is still trying to use it.